# i am trying to open Android Activity from cutomlistadapter with listview buttons. i tried at mt best but no result?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity

I am trying to open activitys with listview buttons. no errors with this code but activitys not opening.I searched all over google as possible as I can but nothing helped me.

here is MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private ListView listView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);


        final ArrayList<Card> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new com.enteruki.deeprelaxation.Card("drawable://"+R.drawable.uki,"Test one"));
        list.add(new com.enteruki.deeprelaxation.Card("drawable://"+R.drawable.beach1,"Beach"));
        list.add(new com.enteruki.deeprelaxation.Card("drawable://"+R.drawable.bonfire,"Bon Fire"));
        list.add(new com.enteruki.deeprelaxation.Card("drawable://"+R.drawable.forests1,"Forest"));
        list.add(new com.enteruki.deeprelaxation.Card("drawable://"+R.drawable.frogs,"Frogs"));
        list.add(new com.enteruki.deeprelaxation.Card("drawable://"+R.drawable.heavyrain,"Heavy Rain"));
        list.add(new com.enteruki.deeprelaxation.Card("drawable://"+R.drawable.insects,"Insects"));
        list.add(new com.enteruki.deeprelaxation.Card("drawable://"+R.drawable.lightning,"Lightning"));
        list.add(new com.enteruki.deeprelaxation.Card("drawable://"+R.drawable.underwater,"Under Water"));
        list.add(new com.enteruki.deeprelaxation.Card("drawable://"+R.drawable.windstrome,"Wind Storme"));

        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_main,list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position==0){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TestoneActivity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(intent,0);
                }
                else if (position == 1)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),BeachActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check onItemClick() method is called or not?

Comment: remove the if/else & try a clean code-block using startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), TestoneActivity.class)))

Comment: @pablopatarca i have total 9 activitys how do i open those with these.

Comment: my suggestion is to clear the doubt that it is a problem of context or for the method startActivityForResult()

Comment: @pablopatarca i am not able see whats wrong in this code i rechecked everything.i have listview with cards inside cards one imageview and one textview and one button. in that listview i am displaying 9 cards. so that means each card have one button itself.i want to open an activity when i click those buttons.i want to open another actitivity with button i place in listview. sorry for my bad english

Comment: That is the point, the method setOnItemClickListener respond to the click event over the row but if you do click over the button the event should not be launched.
For another way, cards is better be used with RecyclerView... I recommend that.

Answer (score 2):

You should create the intent with your Activity context. So, you need to change the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TestoneActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestoneActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on the first and second item only.

```
if (position==0){
   // first               
}
else if (position == 1) {
  // second            
}
```